# How to use login sessions in Typo3 multiple subdomains?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, felogin

I am using version 8 of TYPO3 and I ask your help to know if it is possible to use the login session of a domain in another subdomain, within the same installation?
For example, log in to www.example.com/login and use the session on a.example.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the correct cookieDomain.
This example is for your suggested behaviour:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cookieDomain'] = '.example.com';
```

You can set this with `FE` for frontend only, `BE` for backend only and `SYS` for the general behaviour (which will be overwritten by `FE` or `BE`).